# JQuery button: Style change on js event or CSS only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to mimic jquery's button style for a table row without copying and pasting blocks of CSS code from the jquery style sheet. Unfortunately, it seems the jquery button has some sort of listener on it to tell the tag to switch to a different class (from `ui-btn-up-c` to `ui-btn-hover-c`).

Would it be cleaner to just copypaste all the css code I need and use `:hover` type tag for different styles or add some custom event listener that directs the table row to use `ui-btn-up-c` or `ui-btn-hover-c` as needed?

Thanks!

PS: I know you can buttonize things with `.button()`, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve here - I just want some of the looks of a jquery button.

Comment: Yes copy paste all the `CSS`. Finally you will need that CSS `classes` which you are trying to apply with jQuery.

Comment: Would i be correct in saying that you want certain buttons to have a style which you specify in a css file? Also you want the style to change depending on wether you are hovering over them or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this effect by using classes with buttons. So give each button in a row a different class depending on how you want it to look and define that class in css like below:

html:

```
<button class='MyButtonClass1'>Class Button</button>
```

css:

```
.MyButtonClass1 {
    margin:3px;
    text-align:center;
}

.MyButtonClass2 {
    margin:5px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

[This will explain it better](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/button/cssbutton.html)

Here is a jsfiddle with the above code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy CSS blocks from `.ui-btn-up-c` and `.ui-btn-hover-c`.
The buttons still may not look exactly the same if so,
Copy the css of other classes that might be in use in the original jQuery buttons and add them to your css.